# Not understanding results from strtok()

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

I'm working on parsing a file and have been attempting to use the `strtok()` function to try and help with the process.  Imagine this excerpt from a text file:

```
.text
main:
        lw $a0, array
        lw $a2, size
loop:
        add $t2, $a0, $t2
        sw $t0, 0($t2)
        bne $t3, $zero, loop

        li $v2, 8
        syscall

.data
array:    .word 0:10
message: .asciiz "Hello"
```

I am currently grabbing a file similar to this line by line.  I want to know when I have a line that contains a colon at the end such as `main:`, `loop:`, `array:`, and `message:`.

To do that I tried using this bit of code,

```
char *token;
token = strtok(line, ":");
if (token != NULL)
{
        //Do things with the token I grabbed
}
```

So when I call `strtok` only once, and save it as token, I assumed I was only storing a value for token if the delimiter existed in the line. Otherwise token would be NULL.  So I thought if I checked to see if token was not null, if it passed I would definitely have a line in which the token had a ":" thus I would grab the lines that I originally wanted.

When this code is executed in my program, I am grabbing the first "word" of every line and saving it as token.  Also for lines in which there is nothing (blank line) it saves something gas well because it's not being considered NULL.

This may have came out a little confusing, so if clarification is needed let me know.

Comment: I don't understand why you use strtok in this case, if you only want to check substring, use strstr

Comment: How can I use strstr if I'm not sure what I'm looking for, I just know it will have a ":" in it?

Comment: You don't know what are you looking for? Don't you say you want to know when you have a line that contains colon? then just do token = strstr(line, ":") or just loop from the end to find the colon. Strtok is used to split a string.

Comment: Ah strstr worked.  So if I saved "loop:" in token, how do I remove the : from the string?

Comment: remove last character is easy, token[strlen(token)-1] = 0

Comment: Remember that `strtok()` finds token boundaries in a string and writes a null at the end of a token (so it modifies the input string).  When the delimiter does not appear, the whole string is the token, so you'll get a pointer to the start of the string, not NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If you `strtok(":")` a line that doesn't contain `:`, you don't get `NULL`, you basically get just the line. So the method you're using is not going to work.

If you just want to see if a string ends with `:`, you can use:

```
int len = strlen (str);
if ((len > 1) && (str[len-1] == ':'))
    itEndsWithAColon();
```

Note that you may need to strip trailing white-space (including `\n` if you've gotten the line with `fgets`) before doing this. One way to do this would be to move the whole thing into a function, something like:

```
#include <ctype.h>
int endsWithColonIgnoreWs (char *str) {
    char lastnonws = *str++;
    if (lastnonws != '\0') {
        while (*str != '\0') {
            if (! isspace (*str))
                lastnonws = *str;
            str++;
        }
    }
    return (lastnonws == ':');
}
```